# Is object storage allowed to be implicitly or explicitly reused if lifetime ended?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lifetime, c++17

Consider the following example:

```
// create some storage
alignas(int) char buffer[2 * sizeof(int)];

// new object of type int at the storage of buffer, the int pointed
// to by p begins its lifetime here, buffer's lifetime is over
int* p = new (buffer) int{42};

// some entirely unrelated int
int j = 17;
```

Is it allowable for the other storage at the end of `buffer`, the part that isn't already used by the new `int` object pointed to by `p`, to be reopened to the stack and implicitly reused by subsequent objects of automatic storage duration? In other words, is a conforming implementation allowed to have `&j == p+1`?

---

Relatedly, would *explicitly* reusing the other storage be well-defined behavior?

```
alignas(int) char buffer[2 * sizeof(int)];
int* p = new (buffer) int{42};
int* q = new (p+1) int{6};
```

That is, are both `int`s pointed to by `p` and `q` still within their lifetimes?

Comment: I imagine it's allowed (via the as-if rule) but not done - much easier to move the stack pointer than go find it on the heap

Comment: Why do you say that `buffer`s lifetime is over?

Comment: If compiler can prove that ´p+1´ will not be used by application otherwise, then how would you notice (other than by doing UB pointer comparisons)  if it used that memory?

Comment: The only thing I found under **3.8 Object lifetime** of the C++11 standard for arrays is *The lifetime of an array object starts as soon as storage with proper size and alignment is obtained,and its lifetime ends when the storage which the array occupies is reused or released.* It doesn't say anything about partial re-use of arrays.

Comment: @RSahu Since the standard states *when the storage which the array occupies is reused* isn't placement new reusing the storage thus ending the lifetime of the array?

Comment: @NathanOliver, Barry's code partially re-uses the memory occupied by the array. It's not clear whether the lifetime of the rest of the objects of the array end when an array is partially re-used.

Comment: @RSahu That sentence doesn't exist in the standard anymore.

Comment: @Barry, are you talking about C++14/17?

Comment: @RSahu Yeah, I didn't realize that this stuff changed. Tagged the question as appropriate.

Comment: @Barry The quote is replace with *The lifetime of an object o of type T ends when [...] the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an object that is not nested within o*

Comment: The concept of "storage" and "object lifetime" and "reuse" was pretty vague last time I standard delved, to the level of being unusable other than "you know how it should work, it works that way" interpretation.  In practice, automatic reuse of the storage would be madness, and practical implementations (of code like variant/any/std function/etc) require that you can take some storage S, use it for object A, destroy object A then reuse the same storage S for object B, and not just the storage of A.  I know C++17 had some fixes, but ... I wouldn't hold out hope.

Comment: @hyde well, `p->~int(); new(buffer) int[2]{1,2};` goes and uses the second part of the buffer.  It might be surprising if that overwrote `j`.

Comment: Under P0137, the right thing to do is to just use an array of `unsigned char`. Then creating an object within it doesn't end its lifetime and everything else sort of *just works*. This sidesteps the whole mess.

Comment: @t.C. [P0137](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0137r0.html) for those who want to read it.  I cannot see a mention of `unsigned char` there in r0?  And isn't `aligned_storage_t` the right thing to do here?

Comment: @Yakk You need [r1](http://wg21.link/p0137r1).

Comment: @Yakk: I don't understand why you claim that reuse of unused parts of the stack frame would be "madness". It's not about object destruction, it's about effective lifetime vs formal lifetime. i.e. it's as though OP had written `{ char buffer[whatever]; /* etc etc */ } int j = 17;`. Would you think it's madness to use the space on the stack formerly taken up by `buffer` for `j`, in that case?

Comment: @einpoklum No, except in that case, you using `buffer` after the end of the block is undefined behavior.  In the OP's case, destroying `p->~int()` then reusing the memory at the `buffer` location is legal.  The compiler to automatically detect that would have to prove that that doesn't happen for the compiler to be able to do that legally.  In the scope ending case, the compiler doesn't have to prove you didn't do undefined behavior.  Hence, one is madness to ask a compiler to do it (especially considering the tiny return), the other is easy for the compiler to do.

Comment: @Yakk: You mean it is a compiler error. Anyway, in OP's case, IIANM he's asking about the cases in which the compiler has proven to itself that  `buffer` is _not_ used anymore - and beyond that point I don't see the madness. But it looks like we're not really disagreeing.

Comment: @einpoklum And having compilers do that proof is exactly the madness I'm talking about.  It may even depend on if anyone can ever have a stored pointer into the buffer proper at the time the reuse happens.  The as-if rule permits *a lot of insanity*, to the level where variables cease to exist.

Comment: @Yakk: Variables exist in higher-level languages, compiler produce, well, let's say they produce some kind of IR. So yeah, no variables. Hopefully there's method to the madness :-)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not have to use unique areas of memory for each variable in a stack, and as long as it can determine, that the program can not measure the re-use - e.g. checking whether the two variables have the same address, would possibly cause the compiler to ensure they didn't share memory.

Example

```
int a;
// do some stuff with a.

int b; 
// do some stuff with b.
```

Assuming that both a and b use stack, they may share the address as the compiler can tell their distinct usage.

Creating an item on the stack is a simple instruction

```
sub stackPointer, #AmountOfSpaceNeeded
```

In this example, the amount of space does not affect the speed of allocation.

Creating an item on the heap requires finding some unused area of memory, or "mapping" some new address space in, and takes many times the cost of the one (or two with a frame pointer) instructions for using the heap.

It may also create false-positives on memory checkers, where there is a disagreement about the usable amount of spare memory in an object.

So there is little value in the optimization of using a location in the heap, to save storage on the stack, as

1. Not all functions use the heap
2. There is no time saving in using just the heap
3. The code mechanisms behind the heap may perform measurement (buffer-overrun detection), which results in the compiler breaking the `as-if` rule.
4. As well as determining that the space is unused, the compiler would also need to determine that the life of the memory was correct, as heap objects can be destroyed before a function/block of code finishes.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is totally fine.

```
alignas(int) char buffer[2 * sizeof(int)];
```

Allocate 8 bytes on the stack.

```
 int* p = new (buffer) int{42};
 int* q = new (p+1) int{6};
```

Those new operators doesn't allocate memory to construct the objects, instead they use buffer.

**But please note, the lifetime of those objects will be the lifetime of the buffer variable.** When buffer will be destroyed, memory that p & q are reference to, will be destroyed to.

Also in general case you suppose to call destructor manually before the buffer will be destroyed.

So the answer to the question "Is object storage allowed to be implicitly or explicitly reused if lifetime ended?" is **No**. When buffer's life time ended it is not safe to keep using it's memory because later it will be used for other stack variables.

P.S. I believe you do understand that in your case it will be easier to do manage memory like this;

```
int buffer[2];
int* p = &buffer[0];
int* q = &buffer[1];
```

[image]

Comment: You can't assign a `char*` to an `int*`.

Comment: This answers the second part but ignores the first part of the question.

Comment: What about OP's example? With variable `j`?

Comment: This is not correct, because the objects have explicit lifetime. They must be manually  `delete`d. It is not tied to the buffer, but must stay within the buffer lifetime.